# How to get path parameters and matrix parameters from the following uri string? Uri is /flights/flightid;numberofseats=2/date

Tags: java, regex, rest, jersey

Am trying to separate the path param and matrix param from the following uri string in jersey.

**/flights/flightid;numberofseats=2/date.**

Things I wanna separate following parameters using jersey

1. Flightid
2. numberofseats
3. date

I tried all this code to separate but am failing miserably.

```
@GET
@Path(value = "/flight/{flightid}/{date}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response bookFlight(@MatrixParam("numberofseats") int numberOfSeats,
        @PathParam(value = "flightid") int flightid,
        @PathParam(value = "date") String date) {
    //Logic
}
```

Comment: facing similar problem..

Comment: Did you try using Integer instead of int?

Comment: Is it valid to have a slash after a matrix parameter? I dont see that in any examples.

Answer (score 0):

All matrix param examples I know carry them at the and of the URI. In your case the regex derived from your `Path` would eat up all URI parts and leave nothing for the `@PathParam` to capture. See section 3.7.3 of the [JAX-RS 2.0 Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-eval-spec/index.html).

If possible, move theses parameters to the end.

Or parse flightid (which would contain the matrix params, I think) in your own code.